# About Borel sets and random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, borel-sets

$$\xi, \eta - \text{Randomvariables}$$
How to show that $\forall \xi,\eta \quad \{\omega \mid\xi(\omega) = \eta(\omega)\}$-Borel  set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\xi -\eta$ is a a random variable so $(\xi-\eta)^{-1} \{0\}$ is measurable.

Comment: That $\xi - \eta$ is random variable is ok, $(\xi - \eta)^{-1}(\{0\})=\{\omega\ |\ (\xi - \eta)(\omega) = 0\} \in \mathcal F$, but why it is Borel set?

Comment: Where are your random variables defined? If they are defined on a general probability space there is no such thing as Borel set in the sample space and your question does not make sense.

Comment: In my problem clearly it does not define, where it is, but I can try to determine for myself.

Comment: It will be, when $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B (\mathbb R), \mathbb P)$? $\mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ is Borel algebra

Comment: In that case what is your question? If $f$ is measurable on this space then the inverse image of any Borel set is  a Borel set by definition. So $(\xi -\eta)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is  a Borel set. I have no idea where your confusion is. @anykk

Comment: I understood that! Thanks